# Infinite Design (vector art) alternatives for Windows?

Tags: windows, drawing, vector-graphics

Infinite Design is a fantastic drawing program for Android devices (maybe also iOS?). I'm looking for something that has similar features, but for Windows. Free would be great, but I could also spend money.

The features that I'm looking for:

- Vector art
- Pressure sensitivity (should work with the Surface Pen)
- round and/or nice tapered brush
- Segment tool - it lets you slice off parts of a stroke that are overlapped with another stroke
- SVG/png/jpg export

Nice to have:

- Infinite canvas

Some things that I've tried, and why they didn't work:

- Sketchbook Pro - works great, but raster not vector
- Inkscape - no segment tool (that I can see), and the default brush tool doesn't really taper the way I want. Is more mouse focused, so has a lot of visual noise that I don't like.
- InkPaint - Kind of works, but features are really limited (no undo??)

Inkscape is kind of the best option that I have right now, if I could get the brushes to work well and it had a segment tool like Infinite Design.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) which in their own words:

> From 2004 to 2009, Krita was strongly focusing on being a generic
>   image manipulation/painting application in the style of Photoshop or
>   GIMP. Since 2009, the focus is squarely on painting: the Krita
>   community aims to make Krita the best painting application for
>   cartoonists, illustrators, and concept artists.

I know that it is **not** a pure vector package but big part of the problem is that you are drawing in lines so ask for vector but you need brush stroke style which most true vector packages don't offer - because the brush strokes would need very high levels of details to give it.

Features:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Good Tablet Support
- Pressure Sensitive brush strokes *when working with a tablet*
- Brush Stabilizers
- Multiple, brushes plus customisation
- Multiple Layers
- Export vector layers to .svg
- Export to png & jpeg plus lots of others
- User selected number of undo operations (0=Unlimited)
- Templates

Screenshot from the Krita web site:
[image]